# Requested Style can not be used

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have added a new SLD style for my nyc_roads layer but no map is displayed with the new style. I get the error "The requested Style can not be used with this layer. The style specifies an attribute of NAME and the layer is: wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads".

The named layer has already been named as suggested but still the same error appears. Why?

```
 <Name> wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads </Name>
```

Comment: Thomas B. solution is the right approach, In my case, I change the code of the SLD file directly in Geoserver and it works. I changed the SLD file in a text editor before, then I imported to Geoserver, the results are quite strange:
- the first change was right (ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>), line 15 in my case
- next changes were strange (ogc:PropertyName>-0099.00</ogc:PropertyName>), lines 37,59,89,103 and 125 For that reason, I found that made the changes in the Geoserver works fine, hope it could help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the attribute "NAME" is written in capital letters in your style and your column name of your layer/service is "name" without capital letters.could that be?

Comment: Thanks, I think you are pointing me into the right direction. Still couldn`t make it work though.This is where I found the "NAME" in the code:                     
        <Rule>
        <MaxScaleDenominator>32000</MaxScaleDenominator>
        <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>NAME</ogc:PropertyName>  
        </Label>  
Even if I write my layer name here instead of NAME I get same type of error "The style specifies an attribute of wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads and the layer is: wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads".Tried with just layername and also as NAME="wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads".

Comment: <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>