# GeoServer SLD ServiceExceptionReport:The style specifies an attribute of "Layer" and the layer is: "Workspace:Layer"

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-sld-service

This is the follow-up to this question [Displaying Layer values using Graphs or Histograms in GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415363/displaying-layer-values-using-graphs-or-histograms-in-geoserver). I have looked at various solutions suggested and I seem not to be implementing them correctly. I have implemented the small letters for the fields/columns headings, tried removing underscores, confirmed the spelling for the fields, I am unsure about whitespace. I am still getting the same service exception error. Here is my recent SLD code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Spill:crude_oil</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Pie charts</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke/>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                  xlink:href="http://chart?cht=bvg&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&amp;chd=t:${zones};${losswell};${prodequip};${prodwell};${prodleak};${fpso};${allision};${storage};${refinery};${pipeline};${loading};${equipment}"/>
                <Format>application/chart</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Add>
                  <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                    <ogc:Div>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>crude_oil</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>20000000.0</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Div>
                    <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Mul>
                </ogc:Add>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I tried to implement the following to no success:

[the requested Style can not be used](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131506/the-requested-style-can-not-be-used)
[Error: The requested Style can not be used with this layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273335/error-the-requested-style-can-not-be-used-with-this-layer)
[Geoserver cannot find named layer in external SLD file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227878/geoserver-cannot-find-named-layer-in-external-sld-file)

Comment: Please add the exact error that geoserver gives you

Comment: @IanTurton kindly advise how to check that.

Comment: there must be an error or it would be working?

Comment: Definitely, something is not right and I do not know where the problem is, I will keep researching and trying.

Comment: Please also show how you're making the GetMap? From the error message, it seems GeoServer is looking for a "Spill:crude_oil" layer that is not available for some reason... however, that would occur only if the SLD was sent along with the request.

Comment: @AndreaAime that is correct I can preview the layer successfully when I do the GetMap request with no SLD, the problem is when I sent the request along the SLD, the confusion is where to put the Layer and Workspace: Layer in the SLD

Comment: localhost:8080/geoserver/Spill/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Spill:crude_oil&styles=&bbox=11.6761074066162,-17.2666797637939,16.6146430969238,-4.38610744476318&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers